# glTexImage2D convert alpha to rgba openGL ES

Tags: c++, opengl-es, io

I'm trying to convert working openGL code to openGL ES.  After some digging, I've concluded the following function doesn't work in ES because converting between format and internalFormat isn't supported (i.e. the source and destination formats need to be the same).  The easiest fix seems to be converting the alpha data to rgba where `r=g=b=0` which is what openGL was doing before under the surface.  My attached fix doesn't seem to work though, because 
I don't think I am understanding how the buffer is formatted to make that conversion manually.  Also maybe there is an openGL ES function I can call that will make this copy for me.  Not sure if it matters but the file is a TGA file.

```
void foo( unsigned char *inBytes,
          unsigned int inWidth, 
          unsigned int inHeight ) {
    int error;

    GLenum internalTexFormat = GL_RGBA;
    GLenum texDataFormat = GL_ALPHA;

    if( myAttemptedFix ) {
            texDataFormat = GL_RGBA;

            unsigned char rgbaBytes[inWidth * inHeight * 4];
            for(int i=0; i < inWidth * inHeight; i++) {
                rgbaBytes[4*i] = 0;
                rgbaBytes[4*i + 1] = 0;
                rgbaBytes[4*i + 2] = 0;
                rgbaBytes[4*i + 3] = inBytes[i];
            }
            inBytes = &rgbaBytes[0];

    }


    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureID );

    error = glGetError();
    if( error != GL_NO_ERROR ) {        // error
        printf( "Error binding to texture id %d, error = %d\n",
                (int)mTextureID,
                error );
        }    

    glPixelStorei( GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1 );
    if( mRepeat ) {
        glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT );
        glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT );
        }
    else {
        glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP );
        glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP );
        }

    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
    glTexEnvf( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE );

    glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0,
                  internalTexFormat, inWidth,
                  inHeight, 0,
                  texDataFormat, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, inBytes );

    error = glGetError();
    if( error != GL_NO_ERROR ) {        // error
        printf( "Error setting texture data for id %d, error = %d, \"%s\"\n",
                (int)mTextureID, error, glGetString( error ) );
        }
}
```

Edit: When I run my fix it outlines the sprite correctly but also puts a lot of junk at the bottom that kind of looks like braille:

[image]

Comment: Why do you use GL_ALPHA as format and GL_RGBA as internal format? These values should match each other. If you have a texture with only one value per pixel you should use GL_RED for both format and internal format.

Comment: @dari: `GL_RED` is not a valid internal format in any version of OpenGL ES.

Comment: When you say "doesn't seem to work", can you describe what exactly the problem is? Also, what are your values for `inWidth`, `inHeight`, and `mRepeat`?

Comment: Generally `inWidth` and `inHeight` are 64 and `mRepeat` is `false`.  I've also included an image.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks more like a C++ problem. I believe your corrupted data is caused by this (shortened) code structure:

```
if (myAttemptedFix) {
    unsigned char rgbaBytes[inWidth * inHeight * 4];
    inBytes = &rgbaBytes[0];
}
```

The scope of `rgbaBytes` is the body of the `if`-statement. So the memory reserved for the array becomes invalid after the closing brace, and its content becomes undefined beyond that point. But you make your `inBytes` variable point at this memory, and use it after `rgbaBytes` has gone out of scope.

Since `inBytes` then points at unreserved memory, it's very likely that the memory is occupied by other variables in the code between this point and the `glTexImage2D()` call. So the content gets trashed before `inBytes` is consumed by the `glTexImage2D()` call.

The easiest way to fix this is to move the `rgbaBytes` declaration outside the `if`-statement:

```
unsigned char rgbaBytes[inWidth * inHeight * 4];
if (myAttemptedFix) {
    inBytes = &rgbaBytes[0];
}
```

You'll probably want to make the code structure a little nicer once you have this all figured out, but this should at least make it functional.

Comment: You're right!  Thank you so much.  I'm too used to not dealing with that kind of thing in Python.